# Merge all workflows to a process builder

Tags: workflow, process-builder

Is it a good idea to merge all workflows into a process builder. I mean, add a criterion for each workflow and ask the process builder to evaluate next criteria all every time till the last one.

what would be the pro and con for this.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The pro is that it will be easier to maintain and control the order of operation. The con would be that Process Builder counts against governor limits, so it doesn't play well with triggers.

In general, if you have no triggers, Process Builder would be a better idea, but it you do, workflow rules are still better.